# Bind IConfigurationSection with refreshable config in console application without DI

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm having a problem making typed configuration refreshable in .Net Core Console Application.

The app will load typed objects from configuration...

```
{
     "LibrarySettings": {
       "SettingA": "ValueA",
       "SettingB": "ValueB"
     }
}
```

... and pass them down to libraries as `IOption<SomeLibrarySettings>`

```
public class LibrarySettings
{
    public string SettingA { get; set; }
    public string SettingB { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessLogic
{
    private IOptions<LibrarySettings> _settings;

    public BusinessLogic(IOptions<LibrarySettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public string GetValueA => _settings.Value.SettingA;

    public string GetValueB => _settings.Value.SettingB;
}
```

During runtime if I change `appsettings.json` I will expect the underlying `IOptions` instance to update the values accordingly.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);

        var configuration = builder.Build();

        LibrarySettings settings = new LibrarySettings();

        configuration.Bind("LibrarySettings", settings);

        BusinessLogic logic = new BusinessLogic(Options.Create(settings));

        while (true)
        {
            configuration.Reload();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(logic.GetValueA);
            Console.WriteLine(logic.GetValueB);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that is not the case. When I launch this code and change the values in the copied over `appsettings.json` the values in the app don't get reloaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's a `Bind` extension method on `IConfiguration`. I'm wondering if you need to call that and then pass the result to `Options.Create` (which I *think* exists just so you can create an `IOption`<T>` directly). Something like `var x = new LibrarySettings(); configuration.Bind("LibrarySettings", x); var settings = Options.Create(x);` But that is entirely a guess

Comment: I tried this now and it didn't work. It makes more sense than my initial example though, I updated it in my original question - thanks! On another note, now it seems to me it might not be as easy to do this as I initially thought as all the examples I'm finding use IOptionsSnapshot instead of IOptions. I can't create an instance of IOptionsSnapshot by myself.

Comment: What version of `.NET Core`?

Comment: .Net Core 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

use `IOptionsSnapshot` insted of `IOptions`

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
     private IOptionsSnapshot<LibrarySettings> _settings;

     public BusinessLogic(IOptionsSnapshot<LibrarySettings> settings)
     {
         _settings = settings;
     }

     public string GetValueA => _settings.Value.SettingA;

     public string GetValueB => _settings.Value.SettingB;
 }
```

ref [Options patterns in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1#reload-configuration-data-with-ioptionssnapshot)

EDIT: to avoid common error (`'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor`)

```
public class LibrarySettings
{
    public string SettingA { get; set; }
    public string SettingB { get; set; }
    public LibrarySettings() {}
}
```

Got it to work:

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);

            var configuration = builder.Build();

            var settings = new LibrarySettings();

            configuration.GetSection("LibrarySettings").Bind(settings);

            var x = settings.SettingA;
        }

    }

    public class BusinessLogic
    {
        private LibrarySettings _settings;

        public BusinessLogic(IOptionsSnapshot<LibrarySettings> settings)
        {
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }

        public string GetValueA => _settings.SettingA;

        public string GetValueB => _settings.SettingB;
    }
    public class LibrarySettings
    {
        public string SettingA { get; set; }
        public string SettingB { get; set; }
        public LibrarySettings() { }
    }
```

Comment: Yes but how do I get an instance `IOptionsSnapshot<LibrarySettings>' that is bound to configuration? This is a console app and I'm not using asp.net DI container, so I have to bind it manually somehow.

Comment: do you have this error `'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor`?

Comment: No I get no errors. As you can see in my example I am attempting to use Options.Create() to get an instance of IOptions, where I should probably be using IOptionsSnapshot, but I can't figure out how to create it.

Comment: I tried your updated example, it's not working for me. I think you misunderstand what I'm trying to achieve. To bind appsettings.json to POCO class is not a problem. To have that value refresh during runtime when appsettings.json is updated - I can't get this to work. This is why I included infinite loop in example - to test if settings.SettingA is refreshed when I change appsettings.json in build directory when app is already running.